# effective sample size 2d array using arviz and pymc3 mcmc

Tags: python, pymc3, mcmc, arviz

I'm trying to get the effective sample size for a 2D mcmc chain, using pymc3 and arviz

```
import pymc3 as pm3
!pip install arviz 
import arviz as az

ess = az.ess(samples)
```

The above code works for 1D, but not for 2D, and I see there is a az.convert_to_dataset that might help, but I can't figure out how to use it?

Samples would be an N x 2 array and it should just give a single number as the output

Thanks!

Comment: "It should give a single number": are you sure?  The ESS is parameter-specific.  The ESS can be (wildly) different for different model parameters in the same chain of MCMC samples.

Comment: Ah okay, so I want a single number per parameter and I can do the working 1D ess on the relevant part of the sample array - ace, thanks!

Comment: @Lizardinablizzard assuming you have `N` draws from 2 parameters you can prepend a dimension with `[None, ...]` or with `np.expand_dims` to comply with the convention I explained below

Comment: Also, tangentially related question, are you using PyMC3 to generate the samples? If so, have you tried `arviz.from_pymc3`?

Comment: I've written my own mcmc sampler, and then I get the accepted 2D sample points as an output of size N x 2, so maybe I need to expand dims?

Comment: I've written my own mcmc sampler, and then I get the accepted 2D sample points as an output of size N x 2, so maybe I need to expand dims?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the info from this comment, I hope it starts making things clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with arrays, ArviZ assumes the following shape convention:

- 1d array represents the draws of a single chain of a scalar variable: `(draw,)`
- 2d array represents the draws of multiple chains of a scalar variable: `(chain, draw)`
- 3d+ array represents the draws of multiple chains of multidimensional variables: `(chain, draw, *shape)`

I am not sure why the 2d case is not working for you, I suspect it could be due to not having enough draws to calculate `ess`.

To make sure that your dimensions are being correctly interpreted, I would recommend doing [`idata = az.convert_to_inference_data(ary)`](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/generated/arviz.convert_to_inference_data.html#arviz.convert_to_inference_data) and then checking `idata.posterior` to see the dimensions of the generated object. You can then call `az.ess(idata)` to get the effective sample size.

---

**EDIT**: If I understood your comments correctly, you are generating an array with shape `(draw=N, parameter_dim=2)` as you are only sampling a single chain. As this is a 2d array, it would be interpreted as having `N` chains and `2` draws which should print a warning of having more chains than draws. You can reshape the array to match ArviZ convention with:

```
idata = az.convert_to_inference_data(np.expand_dims(samples, 0))
# or what is the same (we just choose the name of the variable)
idata = az.from_dict({"position": np.expand_dims(samples, 0)})
```

which will generate a `(1, N, 2)` array whose dimensions will be understood by ArviZ. I have already added the conversion to `InferenceData` too as having an `InferenceData` will allow you to call any ArviZ function without having to care about dimensions any more.

---

If your array were `(2, N)`, adding a transpose before expanding the axis should solve the problem:

```
idata = az.convert_to_inference_data(np.expand_dims(samples.T, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks @oriolabril, so I think I needed to take the transpose of my samples to get it into (chain, draw) format, otherwise I get NaN. But now I get an answer of 2.61, when I have ran an MCMC chain with reasonable values of 10000 samples, so I expect something more like 4000? I can see when I plot it, there has been reasonable exploration of the parameter space. When I print idata.posterior, it says chain is 0, 1, draw is 0,....,9999, and x is the sample values?

Comment: are you sampling two chains? Or are you sampling 1 chain with 2 parameters? It is hard to guess what is happening without a minimal example, maybe explaining how did you generate the samples could help, ArviZ integrates with most Python PPL libraries (see https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/notebooks/InferenceDataCookbook.html) so converting the data to a format understandable by ArviZ is a key part of the process

Comment: If you were in the 1 chain and 2 parameters situation but loading into ArviZ generated 2 chains and 1 parameter, it is not unexpected to get 2.6 as ESS, you'd be considering the 2 parameters as the same object, whose distribution would most probably be multimodal. ArviZ implements by default the algorithm from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08008.pdf which as said in the bottom of page 4: _"For multimodal distributions with well-separated modes, the split-̂R adjustment leads to an ESS estimate that is close to the number of distinct modes that are found"_

Comment: I think it's 1 chain of 2 parameters. In my mcmc algorithm, I start at a 2D coordinate and then walk around, if the move is accepted, the coordinates are stored in the N x 2 chain, until N moves are accepted. I'm trying something like ```az.ess(az.convert_to_inference_data(np.transpose(samples)))``` but now I see why it would be close to 2, although I'm not sure how to fix it, I'll check out the cookbook, thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks @oriolabril! I now get two different numbers out ~400, but I think I'm actually aiming for one number, because the dimensions are correlated? I don't think it would be right to just add them. I guess I take some euclidean distance in 2D space between the sample points to make the sample array actually 1D, or are there better methods? Edit: ah, I think I need to read the arxiv paper, thanks!

Comment: You are actually aiming for 2 values, each parameter will have its ess, independently of how correlated they are. Moreover, even with correlated parameters, the two ess can be arbitrariy different